# Woocommerce My account page sidebar is visible only in main language of the site not visible in second language

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am using WPML plugin in word press. I have two languages in my site. Main language is English other is Italian.

My account page sidebar is visible only in main language of the site but when i am changing the language from English to Italian, the default sidebar is not visible in "Italian" Language.

Please suggest something, how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: please follow this link i think it will resolve the issue : https://wpml.org/forums/topic/my-account-sidebar-not-showing-in-second-language/

Comment: I have already tried it. But  this is not working for me.

Comment: Ask WPML dedicated support, opening a ticket… StackOverFlow don't handle any software support

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix. Just posting here in case anyone face the same issue.

The issue was that, i was translating the slug of the my-account page in Italian language. Due to this the sidebar was not working. When i renamed the slug back to my-account then it works.

I don't know why it was not working with the translated slug but i fixed it in this way.